# How to enable C++11 for Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-studio

I'm using Android studio 1.3.2+ndk-r11b-windows-x86_64 and try to build project with native code and C++11 features (share_ptr, weak_ptr and etc.) but got some errors. For example:

> Error:(22, 6) error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type

The issue is: how to use C++11 with Android Studio+NDK?

p.s.
I added flag `cppFlags.add ("-std=c++11")` into "build.gradle"

```
 android.ndk {
        moduleName = "game"
        cppFlags.addAll(["-I${file("src/main/jni/native_app_glue")}".toString(),
                         "-I${file("src/main/jni")}".toString(),
                         "-I${file("src/main/jni/data")}".toString()])
        cppFlags.add ("-std=c++11")
        ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "OpenSLES", "log"])
        stl        = "stlport_static"
}
```

but it's seems didn't work.

Comment: I would consider switching from stlport to libc++ or gnustl.

Comment: switched to gnustl

Comment: Replaced the string "stl = stlport_static" to "stl = gnustl_static" in the file "build.gradle". Thank you for help, Michael.

Comment: Now open in the AOSP bug tracker: [Issue 216331: STLport does not support C++11](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216331).

Answer (score 15):

On build.gradle file of the App I go to android -> defaultConfig -> externalNativeBuild -> cmake and I edit the cppFlags parameter from this

```
cppFlags ""
```

to this

```
cppFlags "-std=c++11"
```

Comment: The OP mentions he's using Android Studio 1.3.2.
Using cmake is possible only since Android Studio 2.2 -- released mid September 2016.

Comment: I enable C++14 in CMake via `set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14 )`. I wonder why this option has no effect when CMake is invoked through Gradle? It works fine when I generate outside of Gradle. Seems like Gradle is pulling some shenanigans.