# What version of c++ does gradle use? Is it the version already installed?

Tags: c++, c++11, gradle, cmake

I use gradle to build my c++ project.The default setting of gradle does not seem to support the c++ 11 standard, how do I configure it?

Comment: Yes, gradle uses [an already installed GCC or MSVC or clang](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_cpp_projects.html#sec:cpp_supported_tool_chain). Which one do you have? You probably want to add a compiler-specific option to your task's compilerArgs.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667374/how-to-enable-c11-for-android-studio) help?